# Load all modules in path from single javascript file

Tags: requirejs, minify, amd, r.js

Is it possible to force RequireJS to rewrite all module load requests within a specific folder to a single file?

as an example, I have a project broken into two modules - 'app' and 'mylibrary'.

Using RequireJS in development mode, I can import modules 'mylibrary/module1', and 'mylibrary/module2' from within the my application code, and this works as you would expect

```
define('myapp',['mylibrary/module1'], function(module1){});
```

However when minified in production, I concatenate all of mylibrary into 'mylibrary.js' and the rest into 'app.js'.

In order to load modules from my minified bundle, I have to define each module individually within my apps requirejs config

```
// app.js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'mylibrary/module1': 'mylibrary.js',
        'mylibrary/module2': 'mylibrary.js',
        'mylibrary/module3': 'mylibrary.js'
    }
});
```

This works, however I have a large list of modules inside 'mylibrary' and would prefer not to have to maintain this separately in another build file.

Is there a way to have requirejs automatically rewrite all requests under a path ('/mylibrary') to a specific file? (That is bundled together with r.js separate from my main build)?

i.e.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'mylibrary/*': 'mylibrary.js'
    }
});
```

In addition, is it also possible to have this configuration only active in my minified production bundle, and not when using the unminified version in development mode?